# credential variable in jenkins publish over ssh

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

This my Jenkins pipeline script. TOOL_CREDS_USR and TOOL_CREDS_PSW variables are not passed to the remote host. Since variables are null, my job hangs asking for username

I verified python command works, verified it by running directly on remote host with variables substituted

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        TOOL_CREDS = credentials('hello')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
                sshPublisher(
                    continueOnError: false, 
                    failOnError: true,
                    publishers: [
                        sshPublisherDesc(
                            configName: "world",
                            sshTransfer(execCommand: 'python3 -m pip install --index-url https://$TOOL_CREDS_USR:$TOOL_CREDS_PSW@sample.com/repository/pypi-hosted/simple testpackage')
                            ],
                            verbose: true
                        )
                    ]
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried ${} but that also fails. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I had to use double quotes instead of single

sshTransfer(execCommand: "python3 -m pip install --index-url https://$TOOL_CREDS_USR:$TOOL_CREDS_PSW@sample.com/repository/pypi-hosted/simple testpackage")